# bash – path agnostic auto completion for local commands

Tags: bash, autocomplete

**tl;dr**: 
Is it possible to somehow get the complete command to match anything that is the last token after the last `/` as a command. 
E.g.:

```
./foo 
~/foo
~/bin/foo
```

Should all match (and complete) the `foo` command.

I tried with `complete -F _foo_complete foo` but this only handles the case where the `foo` command is used without path. I.e. somewhere exists on the path.

**background**

We have a rather big framework and some special tools for developers that support a lot of options. I would like to add completion for these tools, but I can’t assume that they are installed to a specific location nor that there will be only one binary version at a time on the system.

Developers might have different working copies of different versions or multiple configurations (debug, release) lying around at the same time.

Currently we use these tools either from CWD like `./foo …` or with path like `~/devel/framework/build/release/bin/foo …`. I was hoping registering `complete -F _foo_complete foo` will match foo also in these cases, but it looks like it is not on my system.

Is it possible at all? Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved – This is not a problem. 
That it wasn’t working was my own fault. For some reason there was 
`complete -F _minimal ./foo` registered alongside `complete -F _foo_complete foo`. Probably due to not correctly sourcing my own completions after using the default ones coming from the `bash-completion` package.